# Swift Want notification when 10000 steps have been reached on watchos

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit, watchos

I am making a swift watchos app that integrates with a user's step count,Heart Rate and oximeter as reported by the Health app.I would like to find an app that works with the  watch to alert me when I've reached 10,000 steps. Any one please give me an example how to find out steps count 10,000. Thanks in advance.

Comment: tried this ? https://medium.com/geekculture/simple-pedometer-in-swift-482099cf7bbd

Comment: @BlindNinja yes. but its not working properly. can you please send any sample code or github link